# React Webpage only re-renders when I change some code

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

I've got a web application using React. I've been using the useEffect hook to perform a database call on first render, but 90% of the time the code in the useEffect hook never fires, and the 10% of time it does, I can't figure out why. But if I change literally anything in that script (even a console.log) it is guaranteed to fire 100% of the time.

This is how I'm using useEffect to only fire once since its a database read.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        performAction()
      },[])
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how page renders work here?

Comment: it sounds like `performAction()` is an async call and it appears to only work when you use `console.log` because (I believe) something is wrong with the performAction function itself. (it doesn't get the data successfully, but the log does resolve successfully is my guess) Would need to see what that function looks like to help further.

Answer (score 1):

you can just pass the database object/function into the (watch) spot of the useEffect hook! just type your database const or database read function into the square brackets at the end of the useEffect() function!

something like this:

```
useEffect(() =>{performAction(), [yourDatabaseReadFunction()]}
```